# How to remove GNOME Build Tools?

Tags: gnome

Using the following codes, I installed GNOME Build Tool but don't know how to remove them. Tried with "make clean" and similar commands but they don't work.

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/jhbuild
cd jhbuild
./autogen.sh
make
make install
```

I want to delete whole program from my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If `make uninstall` does not work, your're probably out of luck. You can still search for the installed files in the jhbuild folder, and delete the from your filesystem manually.

For future installs: use `sudo checkinstall` instead of `sudo make install`, to install the files as a deb managable by your package manager.

You probably have to install checkinstall first:

```
sudo apt install checkinstall
```

Comment: When i use `make unistall` I get `make: *** No rule to make target unistall.  Stop.`

Comment: exactly. The providers of this sourcecode have to define the uninstall rule for this to work. If they don't you have to do it manually.